# Changing axis values on Matlab figure/graph output?

Tags: matlab, scaling, axis-labels

I have a graph that automatically has x and y axis/values. However, I want to completely get rid of those and put into my own custom values, without changing the appearance of the graph at all.

Currently the x and y scales are pixel coordinates of the image, but I want to get rid of it and make them into centimeters so someone can better understand how large the image is that they are looking at...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the units of an axes with this command:

```
set(YourAxesHandles,'Units','centimeters');
```

and then play around with the scaling/values/whatever you want:

```
set(YourAxesHandles,'XMin',[min max]);
set(YourAxesHandles,'YMin',[min max]);

set(YourAxesHandles,'XTick',[min:increment:max]);
```

and so on. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

I found how to do this, check it out if you want:

```
% I want 8 intervals, so I divide 272 (number of pixels in X)
% by 34 to get 8 splits
set(gca,'XTick',[0:34:272])

% specify the label displayed at each tick mark
set(gca,'XTickLabel',[-4:4])
```

Thanks a lot, you made me look in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry to be so anglo-centric, but is there any chance you could translate the comment into English, as this is an English speaking site?

Comment: Ohh sorry, I just wrote it in french in my program and copy-paste, forgot I was writing on an eglish website. My bad!  Sorry if I'm late! (someone already done that for me.. thanks to that person :) )